# Is there a formal principle which states that THIS IS LOUDER than this?

Tags: capitalization, linguistics

I'm writing a school paper on linguistics and the English language and I'm curious about whether a theory exists outlining why larger words appear louder?  That is, why words either of a greater font size or simply capitalized appear LOUDER than those which are not?

Comment: Well, writing doesn't represent sounds very well, and sounds are language, so you should start with the sounds. That is, why do people capitalize letters when they want you to hear them louder in your mind's ear? And the answer is that things that are bigger correlate with things that are louder, because things that are bigger make bigger noises, for one thing. For another, changing the style to ALL CAPS means changing something in the speech, and the volume is one of the most obvious things that varies. It appears to be a natural instinct, in that individuals arrive at it independently.

Comment: Well, on the Interweb ALL CAPS is called SHOUTING.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, John Lawler wrote:

> Well, writing doesn't represent sounds very well, and sounds are language, so you should start with the sounds. That is, why do people capitalize letters when they want you to hear them louder in your mind's ear? And the answer is that things that are bigger correlate with things that are louder, because things that are bigger make bigger noises, for one thing. For another, changing the style to ALL CAPS means changing something in the speech, and the volume is one of the most obvious things that varies. It appears to be a natural instinct, in that individuals arrive at it independently.

Answer (score 1):

“ALL-CAPS FILL THE SPACE. The message crowds everything else out.

using CAPITAL LETTERS to make words look "louder" [The New Republic Article](https://newrepublic.com/article/117390/netiquette-capitalization-how-caps-became-code-yelling)

> Professor Paul Luna, director of the department of typography and
>   graphic communication at the UK’s University of Reading, told me we’ve
>   been using caps to convey “grandeur,” “pomposity,” or “aesthetic
>   seriousness” for thousands of years—at least since Roman emperors had
>   monuments inscribed, in all caps, with their own heroic
>   accomplishments.

As you mention in your question ... THEORIES ABOUND! The article supplied is a good short read on the subject.

[image: CAPS LOCK]

Answer (score 1):

[A similar question appeared on the History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/41249/when-did-people-decide-that-all-caps-means-the-writer-is-shouting) a few months ago, it's a must read, especially if you are writing a paper on the subject. [This answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/41284) lists examples dating back to the 19th century and argues it was a results from the way print publications were typeset. [Another answer](https://history.stackexchange.com/a/41250) cites a [usenet conversation from 1984](https://groups.google.com/forum/#%21msg/net.flame/VbghoeOfwyI/E2mClWj2GV8J) discussing the subject.

In the usenet conversation three ways to add emphasis, including capitalisation, are named [in this post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/net.flame/VbghoeOfwyI/EQRf347oxw0J):

> 1) using CAPITAL LETTERS to make words look "louder",
>
> 2) using *asterisks* to put sparklers around emphasized words, and
>
> 3) s p a c i n g words o u t, possibly accompanied by 1) or 2).

Attribution for the quote: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/net.flame/VbghoeOfwyI/EQRf347oxw0J

I personally think it is because it attracts attention (because its bigger) and also because it used in that way by others (see the early examples cited in the History SE answer). The last might not be entirely clear, others use it that way, but why would that spread to you? That might be because of an effect called mirroring, see [this article about it Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mirroring_(psychology)).